# Nginx rewrite not working as per docs

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect http://example.com/test/index.php?/Server/Search/IP_ADDRESS  to http://example.com/?ip=IP_ADDRESS

Tried following rewrite rule, but, it is not working.

rewrite  ^/test/index.php?/Server/Search/(.*)$ http://example.com/?ip=$1 redirect;

This is needed for internal purpose as another api will check the IP address at http://example.com/?ip=IP_ADDRESS

Comment: I can't understand what do you want?

Comment: I just want redirect to work :(

Comment: Well. `rewrite` works only with `$uri`, that doesn't include any query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location = /test/index.php {
  if ($args ~ "^/Server/Search/(.+)") {
     set $sip $1;
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /?ip=$sip? redirect;
  }
}
```